# Is having Constants in Interfaces for boolean parameters of Interface methods a good practice or code smell?

Tags: design-patterns, parameters, interface, language-agnostic, anti-patterns

So I have the following Interface:

```
public interface RoleService {
    boolean INCLUDE_DEACTIVE_OBJECTS = true;
    boolean EXCLUDE_DEACTIVE_OBJECTS = false;
    Set<? extends BaseBusinessObject> getOwnedBusinessObjectsOf(final Employee employee, final boolean includeDeactiveObjects);
}
```

and somewhere in an upper layer, an example usage is as follows..

```
if (someCondition) {
    ownedBusinessObjects = roleService.getOwnedBusinessObjectsOf(employee, RoleService.INCLUDE_DEACTIVE_OBJECTS);
} else {
    ownedBusinessObjects = roleService.getOwnedBusinessObjectsOf(employee, RoleService.EXCLUDE_DEACTIVE_OBJECTS);
}
```

So instead of passing values such as `true` (or `false`), I believe it is much easier to read the method call when I say `INCLUDE_DEACTIVE_OBJECTS`.

But I am not sure, is this just plain stupid? Is this an anti-pattern or a code smell or some sort of violation of a best practice?

I think this resembles avoiding [Magic Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad) somehow, but is it as useful or is it rather confusing?

Comment: Kudos for `language-agnostic` tag. It is rarely seen these days on design questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this makes the API more readable, it's fine. It doesn't matter what the underlying value is, it matters that you pass a flag that triggers a certain behaviour. If your language of choice only allows positional argument passing, then such a constant makes the call much more readable. Compare:

```java
roleService.getOwnedBusinessObjectsOf(employee, RoleService.INCLUDE_DEACTIVE_OBJECTS);
roleService.getOwnedBusinessObjectsOf(employee, true);
```

*"Get owned business objects of employee… what?"* Nobody has any idea what "`true`" means here, a named value is much better.

---

The alternative is when your language of choice supports call time named arguments (here, Python):

```py
roleService.getOwnedBusinessObjectsOf(employee, include_deactivated=True);
```

The API should enforce named arguments here (again: Python):

```py
def getOwnedBusinessObjectsOf(employee, *, include_deactivated): ...
```

In Objective-C you'd do something similar with explicit method naming:

```
[roleService getOwnedBusinessObjectsOf:employee includingDeactivated:YES]
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting constant fields inside an Interface is definitely bad, IMO. I come from C# background and it does not even allow const fields in an `Interface`. Even in Java you have [Constant Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface) (anti-pattern again ) whose sole purpose is to contain constants that multiple classes can share. You're not exactly doing that stuff. Still just though of referencing.

> So instead of passing values such as true (or false), I believe it is
>   much easier to read the method call when I say
>   INCLUDE_DEACTIVE_OBJECTS

**Option 1**

To replace constants whilst maintaining readability you could have define 2 methods which indicate if deactive (I would choose 'Inactive' instead. There's deactivate verb but no deactive adjective) objects are included.

```
getOwnedBusinessObjectsIncludingInactive(...)
getOwnedBusinessObjectsExcludingInactive(...)
```

These would be just wrapper methods in `RoleService` class that `private`ly call a method to retrieve actual data, by passing `true` or `false` respectively.

**Option 2**

Have a separate class that defines application level constants in one place.

```
getOwnedBusinessObjectsOf(employee, Constants.INCLUDE_INACTIVE_OBJECTS)
getOwnedBusinessObjectsOf(employee, Constants.EXCLUDE_INACTIVE_OBJECTS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Any method which takes a boolean parameter violates the Single Responsibility Principle because it does one thing for true and a second thing for false.

This is always a code smell. Clean Code tells us to split the method in two:

1. `getOwnedBusinessObjectsIncludingDeactiveObjectsOf(Employee employee);`
2. `getOwnedBusinessObjectsExcludingDeactiveObjectsOf(Employee employee);`

Of course if the method is to be widely used, you will likely want more concise names, e.g. `getAllObjects` and `getActiveObjects`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use words with opposite meanings in your constant naming, you could also try wrapping booleans into an enum.

```
public interface RoleService {

    /**
    * Boolean wrapper for easy reading of values in method parameters.
    */
    enum IncludeDeactiveObjects {

        TRUE(true),
        FALSE(false);

        private final boolean flag;

        private IncludeDeactiveObjects(boolean flag) {
            this.flag = flag;
        }

        public boolean get() {
            return flag;
        }
    }

    Set<? extends BaseBusinessObject> getOwnedBusinessObjectsOf(final Employee employee, final IncludeDeactiveObjects includeDeactiveObjects);
}
```

The calls would be:

```
roleService.getOwnedBusinessObjectsOf(employee, RoleService.IncludeDeactiveObjects.TRUE);
roleService.getOwnedBusinessObjectsOf(employee, RoleService.IncludeDeactiveObjects.FALSE);
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is only for readability, in your abstract class, you can have static variable to hold these boolean values and you can assign with ClassName.AttributeName

```
public YourClass
{
    public bool static INCLUDE_DEACTIVE_OBJECTS = true;
    public bool static EXCLUDE_DEACTIVE_OBJECTS = false;

    public static void Main (String args[])
    {

    }
}
```